# Tortoise SVN ignoring .so files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, shared-libraries

Tortoise SVN on windows is ignoring the .so files. How can I set it to not ignore them, so that I'm able to commit such files.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be committing binary files? That really is outside the scope of intended use for subversion.

Comment: You definitely want to commit binary files which are a part of the build environment if you want a self-contained, "checkout and build", project repository. That ignore pattern is a hiccup in TortoiseSVN's default configuration.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to `settings` and remove *.so from `Global ignore pattern`.

Comment: Are you answering your own question? If so, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: if u would have acceded your answer, i would have +1 it. promise to do so if you'll accept it in the future.

Comment: you save me. i waste so much time in svn:ignore property

Answer (score 0):

When using `svn` on the command line and you don't want to change your settings, the `--no-ignore` option might me the solution (also works work `svn status`):

```
--no-ignore: disregard default and svn:ignore and svn:global-ignores property ignores
```